# Is it really impossible to skip template parameters with default arguments in C++, why does syntax suggest otherwise?

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, default

I've been trying to find a way to skip a template parameter not located at the end of the template parameter list, in a derived class that has been assigned a default in its base class.

I've done some research on this topic, also here on SO. While similar questions have been discussed on SO - many answers basically suggesting it doesn't work were related to very special cases like the hash map case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1276993/2852046). Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2727120) answer by "Potatoswatter", which in my opinion contradicts the impossibility of skipping such a parameter. In his answer he claims this declaration would be valid:

```
template< class A, class B = int, class C >
class X;
```

Assuming it is true that a template parameter may not be skipped (unless at the end of the argument list) such a declaration would make no sense at all. Since B is assigned a default value, but followed by C which has no default, in this case value B would always have to be assigned explicitly, rendering the assignment of int as default for B completely useless. The only scenario where the declaration of X above would make sense is one where one of the following declarations of Y would be valid:

```
class Y : public X<double, , const std::string&> { ... }

class Y : public X<A = double, C = const std::string&> { ... }
```

So is it really impossible to skip a template parameter that is not located at the end of the template parameter list when deriving a specialized class?

If it is impossible why so, and why does legal syntax apparently suggest otherwise (see class X example above)?

If it is in fact *not* impossible, how can one skip a template argument that has been assigned a default?

Comment: I guess `class A, class B = int, class C` is not valid unless in the same translation unit you do have a declaration where `C` *has* a default value

Comment: Nice idea, didn't think of that yet, this would be a very special case where the declaration would make sense, even though skipping is not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant standardese is contained in "Template Parameters [temp.param]" (14.1).

Essentially, a default argument may only be used if the parameter to which it applies is not followed by any non-pack parameters that do not have default arguments ([temp.param]/11). However, the  syntax you quoted is usable in a declaration in the situation described by  [temp.param]/10:

> The set of default template-arguments available for use is obtained by merging the default arguments from
>   all prior declarations of the template in the same way default function arguments are (8.3.6). [*Example*:
>
> ```
> template<class T1, class T2 = int> class A;
> template<class T1 = int, class T2> class A;
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> template<class T1 = int, class T2 = int> class A;
> ```
>
> — *end example*]

Comment: Can you think of any example, except the derivation scenario Piotr mentioned in his comment above, where such a fragmented template declaration would make sense?

Comment: @norritt: No. Not everything that you *can* do with C++ is something you *should* do.

Answer (score 0):

The word "class" is kind of hidden in your question, so I thought I'd mention (even though this isn't exactly an answer) that template parameters with defaults *can* be "skipped", sort of, in calls to *function* templates. Consider [this code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cASrkeTcqVvobNp5):

```
template<class X, class Y = int, class Z>
void foo(X x, Y y, Z z) {
    (void)x, (void)y, (void)z;
    puts(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

int main()
{
    foo(3.14, {}, 1.45f);
}
```

- Template parameter `X` is deduced as `double` (and the default, if any, would go unused).
- Template parameter `Y` cannot be deduced in this call, so the default of `int` is used.
- Template parameter `Z` is deduced as `float`.

Providing defaults for function template parameters happens a lot in the STL these days because of the undeduceability of `{}` in a function argument list. See for example [`std::exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/exchange) or [constructor #8 of `std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional).

You might expect that a similar trick could be used with constructor template argument deduction in C++17, but my experimentation suggests that this is *not* the case. In *class* template definitions, the compiler will produce a diagnostic if you put a template-parameter-with-default earlier in the list than a template-parameter-without-default.

```
template<class X, class Y = int, class Z>  // error!
struct Foo {};
```