# The set of default template-arguments merging

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

please help to understand below scenario

```
template<typename T1,typename T2=int> class A;
template<typename T1=int,typename T2> class A;
template<typename T1,typename T2> class A{ } 
// yields to  template<typename T1=int,typename T2=int> compiling fine
```

but when i use non type template its giving error

```
 template<typename T1,int i=4> class A;
 template<typename T1=int,int i> class A;
 template<typename T1,int i> class A{ }  // error : redefinition of default parameter 2
```

is this merging won't work with template type and non-type ??

Comment: What compiler and which version?

Comment: @T.C visual c++ 2013

Comment: This [should](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32414941) and [does](https://ideone.com/mFoK4E) work. Looks like a compiler bug?

Comment: @KerrekSB seems to be this feature is not in vc++ 2013 or it may be bug .  below code is not working in vc++2013 where as it's working with gc v4.8.3                            
 

void fun(int i,float f=2.13);
void fun(int i=2,float f);
void fun(int i,float f){
    cout << " i = " << i <<endl;
    cout << " f = " << f <<endl;
}

Comment: The issue with default template arguments is present in Visual C++ 2015 as well, so you should report it on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio). The example in your comment above compiles fine in VC++ 2015.